# How to set up media image attribute in magento

Tags: magento-1.6

Hello I am newbie in magneto.
I am trying to add new attribute for browse the image. so i create new attribute with Media Type Successfully but the problem is that it cant be visible on Admin Panel Product Page.
I also setup new attributes in Default attribute set.

Comment: No Need to any ans I got the Problem Solution

Comment: Feel free to post your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The new image upload attribute becomes part of the standard Image uploader. You will notice a new radio button tab there.